# How to get uni polar sinusoidal wave from buck converter?

Tags: pwm, dc-dc-converter, buck, converter

I am trying to build a pure sine wave inverter by using a buck converter cascaded with a square inverter. My hope is that I can vary the duty cycle in such a fashion so as to reach a fully rectified sinusoidal output with desired frequency so he square inverter will give me pure sinusoidal output which can be stepped up using a transformer to run a 25W load.

My question is about the design of Buck converter because I am not sure about how to calculate the values of 'L' and 'C'?
I know the constant duty cycle formulas but if there is another helpful resource here, then I would love to know about it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you mean by cascading a buck converter with a square inverter

Comment: And you can't **hope** a logical system to work !

Comment: Draw a picture of your intentions. At the moment it is unclear what you mean.